# How do I place down an Image In Python?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I have an issue that I can't seem to figure out. I am making a small level designer, and I want to be able to move an image, be able to place it, and then keep on placing that same image. 
I have got the moving image part working, I just can't seem to get it to place the image when I hit enter. 
What I **Think** is happening, is that it places the image, but moves that image along with the one that is moving on the screen.

Not sure.

I was hoping that someone could help me out with this.

Below is my code:

```
import sys
import pygame as pg
from pygame.locals import *
import time
from random import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfile
image_file = "../res/ExampleProject/TankGame/TankGameImg/tileGrass_transitionE.png"

f = open("../Saves/Backups/FailSafe.txt", "a+")
f.write("This is a test")


pg.init()

xcrds = 17
ycrds = 13
black = (0,0,0)
sw = 1440
sh = 700

image = pg.image.load("../res/ExampleProject/TankGame/TankGameImg/barrelRust_side.png")
image = pg.transform.scale(image, (100, 100))

imgrect = image.get_rect()
imgplace = image.get_rect()

Screen = pg.display.set_mode((sw, sh))
Screen_placed = pg.display.set_mode((sw, sh))
pg.display.set_caption(' 2D Level Designer')

imgrect.left = 0
imgrect.top = 0
imgplace.top = 0 + "1"
imgplace.left = 0 + "1"

Screen.blit(image, imgrect)
pg.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == KEYDOWN :              
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:          
                pygame.quit()                  
                sys.exit()     
            if event.key == K_UP:
                imgrect.top -= 5
                imgplace.top -= 5
            if event.key == K_DOWN:
                imgrect.top += 5
                imgplace.top += 5

            if event.key == K_LEFT:
                imgrect.left -= 5
                imgplace.left -= 5

            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                imgrect.left += 5
                imgplace.left += 5

            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                print("Placing Object...")
                Screen_placed.blit(image, imgplace)
                print("Image Placed!")




            if event.key == K_n:
                image_file = askopenfilename()
                image = pg.image.load(image_file).convert_alpha()
                print("Placable Updated!")


    Screen.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clears the previous image.
    Screen.blit(image, imgrect)  # Draws the image at the new position.
    Screen_placed.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clears the previous image.
    Screen_placed.blit(image, imgrect)  # Draws the image at the new position.
    pg.display.update()  # Updates the screen.
```

If you need any extra info, please, ask.

_MouseBatteries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is that you want to place a bunch of images on the screen but you have no way to track and draw a bunch of images. You can do something like this:

```
....
Screen.blit(image, imgrect)
pg.display.update()

placed_objects = []  # this will hold all the locations of the placed objects as rectangles

while True:
....
```

Then when you hit enter, store the rectangle (the place where you want to drop it). It **needs** to be a new rectangle (otherwise, they all move together like you said)

```
 if event.key == K_RETURN:
     print("Placing Object...")
     placed_objects.append(pg.Rect(imgplace.x, imgplace.y, imgplace.width, imgplace.height))
     print("Image Placed!")
```

Then when you draw them:

```
for image_rect in placed_objects:
    Screen.blit(image, image_rect)  # draw the placed image at each stored location
```

**note**: In my code, I eliminated the other screen (Screen_placed). I am not sure why it was there, but it was gumming up the works. I would highly recommend a single screen and ways to track all the objects you create.

**note**: In the future you will not only need to track the rectangles, but the images as well. this way the user can select a new image and start placing those

Answer (score 0):

First you must use Double backslashes: '\\' for your image path

```
image_file = "..\\res\\ExampleProject\\TankGame\\TankGameImg\\tileGrass_transitionE.png"

f = open("..\\Saves\\Backup\\FailSafe.txt", "a+")
image = pg.image.load("..\\res\\ExampleProject\\TankGame\\TankGameImg\\barrelRust_side.png")
```

and your second must be number **strong text**

```
imgplace.top = 0 + 1
imgplace.left = 0 + 1
```

Comment: This, sadly does not fix the issue. Files were loading with single slashes ('/') in the first place. The only issue is, that (if you read my code, which you did) it doesn't place the image down when I hit the enter key.